# wordpress custom menu hierarchy

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am new to wordpress theme integration and I need some suggestion on page hierarchy.

I have page called branding and this page have sub pages brand-x,y,z etc...I need brand-x,y,z should come under branding (www.domainname.com/branding/brand-x)

If I create this hierarchy in wp theme, its getting added as a sub item in the drop down menu under branding page, so I want to retain only the URL for hierarchy for the best practice, don't need in drop down menu item.

If I remove dropdown menu all locating in primary navigation.

Let me know the possibilities?

Thanks,
Gururaj

Comment: what is the dropdown menu you're talking about ?

Comment: we can't help you without knowing what dropdown menu you are referring to and what is that for. From your definition it seems to show child pages, if you don't need it just hide it or remove it.

Comment: I am using wp theme (u-design) from theme forest. branding page has sub pages. if I create these sub pages. in the WP menus I have option of adding as main navigation or sub navigation.if include as sub navigation it creates a drop down menu automatically in the front-end. I have sub pages under each menu item, but I don't want to list as drop down. hope its clear.